# Do perfectly periodic motions (perfect clocks) exist in nature?

Tags: time, error-analysis, atomic-clocks

Periodic motions are used in clocks to measure time quantitatively. If we position a pendulum next to process, we can measure how long the process lasted. If the pendulum executed 3.78 periods it took 3.78 "seconds". We can to attach hands to the clock so it's easier to count the number of periods, like an odometer shows the number of meters counted with a ruler.

It seems to me that truly periodic motions don't exist in nature. They all have periods that vary in, eeeh, time. Time is constituted then by a truly perfect clock.

A ceasium clock is accurate but is its period truly constant? A long pendulum with a heavy mass, swinging in vacuum on a smooth hinge, still experiences tiny friction, slowly altering its period.

Is such process, such a perfect clock, seen in nature? Or will it remain a fantasy forever?

Comment: You can take pretty much any valid physical thing and add the word “perfect” to turn it into a fantasy. So this type of question is rather uninformative.

Comment: @Dale I just ask if clocks have fixed periods. I can't think of a perfect periodic motion. Of course a perfect circular orbit doesn't exist either. I just wonder if it's true for clocks.

Comment: why the obsession with “perfect”? It is a useless concept since nothing is perfect. Can you revise the question to not use the word “perfect”? If not, then it is not a physically relevant question since nothing physical is perfect. There is no need for a “truly perfect” clock

Comment: @Dale That's exactly what my question is about! **If** there exist perfecttly periodic processes, with a time independent period. It's the clock used in relativity, but it has no physical counter part, I think. If not, how can we measure time?

Comment: then it is a pointless question because the answer to any question of the form “does there exist a perfect X” is “no”, regardless of X. And relativity does not require perfect clocks, nor are perfect clocks required for measuring time. A better question would be: since perfect clocks don’t exist how can we measure time or how does relativity work, with some explanation why you think that there is a conflict or problem

Comment: @Dale In a sense, a virtual particle, the disconnected closed one particle propagator in Feynman diagrams, is a perfect clock. You can't tell if the perfect clock goes forward or backward in time (paradoxically it may sound).

Comment: A ceasium clock (in the absence of electric and magnetic fields) is perfect by definition. What is probably a more relevant question is how accurately you can compare two periodic events and whether Cs atoms are the best choice for the time standard.

Answer (score 1):

> Is such process, such a perfect clock, seen in nature? Or will it remain a fantasy forever?

A perfect anything is not seen in nature, so the answer to this question is trivially no and trivially that it is a fantasy. This answer provides no information whatsoever about clocks or time.

> Time is constituted then by a truly perfect clock.

This is not correct. There is no need for truly perfect clocks in the discussion of time any more than there is a need for truly perfect scales in the discussion of mass or truly perfect rulers in the discussion of length.

For clarity, there are multiple concepts that are meant by the unqualified word "time", I will use it to refer to "proper time" which is the usual scientific meaning.

Time is the quantity measured by a clock, any clock will do provided it is used as intended (i.e. pendulum clocks are not designed to be used on the moon, no clock is designed to be used after being smashed). Notice the absence of the word perfect.

In science we are primarily interested in measurements and the scientific method is used to ensure that our theories accurately predict the outcome of measurements. All measurements have some amount of uncertainty, so although time is the quantity measured by a clock our measurements of time all carry some uncertainty. So a correct characterization of any time should include the uncertainty in the measurement.

To estimate the uncertainty in a measurement of any quantity, we simply construct 3 or more identical devices (clocks, rulers, scales, etc.) to measure the same quantity. The disagreement in the measurements of that same quantity gives us our uncertainty. Thus, both time and the uncertainty in our measurement of time can be determined purely from imperfect measurements. There is no need to invoke perfect measurement devices.

Comment: Okay. But... Say we have a clock with a period time that gets smaller after each period. There is no universal standard clock we can compare it with. We can't know if this is the case since there are no perfectly periodic processes. What then does the t on the it-axis of a pseudo Euclidean space mean? You can't measure an exact value of x either, but the x exists physically. It lays in space, out there, in front of your nose. But an exact time doesn't exist. I don't say it that important that an exact time doesn't exist. I'm not obsessed with perfect time. It just that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Felicia then you have a broken clock. Comparing it to a working clock will show that it is broken. Incidentally, that is exactly why we use at least 3 clocks instead of just 2. Also, distance is no more or less physical than time. If you think one exists and the other doesn’t then you are kidding yourself. You can make the exact same objection about distance with a ruler that gets smaller on one side

Comment: *then you have a broken clock.* Haha! :) Distance and space are there in from of your nose. There exist no perfect rulers, but what's measured is there. The thing a clock measures  has no physical correlate. A perfect clock exists in the mind only. Not inside the process, which consists of particles with changing distances. You are fooling yourself...